# PHP installation error

Tags: linux-mint, php

I'm running Linux Mint Maya.  Whenever I try to run a php file from localhost, Firefox tries to download the file.  Apache seems to be working OK and when I type `which php` at a command prompt, I get `/usr/bin/php` but when I type `php -v` I get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib
/php5/20090626+lfs/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/gd.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib
/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on 
line 0

PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 13 2017 
20:37:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago, I fixed it by installing the missing extensions, i.e.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mcrypt
```

If unnecessary, you can try to find out which files are loading the missing extensions, for example (on my machine)

```
$ grep -Hr "extension=" /etc/php5 
/etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini:zend_extension=opcache.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini:extension=json.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini:extension=mcrypt.so
...
```

and comment out the lines in the files giving an error.

**Edit** It is also possible that the specified paths are incorrect, perhaps you can fix them.